# Combining dropdown list and button with ipywidgets

Tags: ipywidgets

I want to filter a dataframe by 1) selecting a specific portfolio from a dropdown menu, 2) selecting other stuff by clicking the checkboxes (for example, display only securities denominated in USD) and 3) hit a button to filter the dataframe.

So basically I need the selection the be past to the dropdown_handler function only after hitting the button, otherwise it keeps recalculating everytime something is changed in the dropdown.

Edit: just changed the code, it should be replicable now.

```
pf_dropdown = Dropdown(options=['ACTIVE', 'DEFENSIVE','DYNAMIC'],value='ACTIVE',description='Portfolio')
output = Output()
display(pf_dropdown, output)

def dropdown_handler(change):
    if change.new == 'ACTIVE':
        port = 'ID-4'
    if change.new == 'DEFENSIVE':
        port = 'ID-5'
    if change.new == 'DYNAMIC':
        port = 'ID-6'
    else:
        print('Error')
    with output:
        output.clear_output()
        print(port)
        
pf_dropdown.observe(dropdown_handler, names='value')
```

Comment: Can't you create your two selection widgets separately ( a dropdown for your portfolios, and checkboxes for your currencies), and then a button which triggers a function via `on_click` to display the filtered dataframe?

Comment: yes thats exactly what I want to achieve!